# Como presentar una consulta con agrupación en el template

Tags: python, django

De antemano son **dos** problemas uno es como presentar la consulta en el template, el otro como poner le un alias. 


Uso una consulta que suma y cuenta por un campo la idea es presentar el **valor** de momento presenta solo la **clave**.

```py
nombAreaNumComp = Competences.objects.values('fkarea__nameareaes').annotate(numCompArea=Count('fkarea')).order_by('fkarea')
```

con un simple print su salida es:

```py
[{'fkarea__nameareaes': 'Información y alfabetización digital', 'numCompArea': 3}, {'fkarea__nameareaes': 'Comunicación y colaboración online', 'numCompArea': 6}, {'fkarea__nameareaes': 'Creación de contenidos digitales', 'numCompArea': 4}, {'fkarea__nameareaes': 'Seguridad en la red', 'numCompArea': 4}, {'fkarea__nameareaes': 'Resolución de problemas', 'numCompArea': 4}]
```

usando un for para presentar la

```py
for k, v in nombAreaNumComp:
  print(k, v)

fkarea__nameareaes numCompArea
fkarea__nameareaes numCompArea
fkarea__nameareaes numCompArea
fkarea__nameareaes numCompArea
fkarea__nameareaes numCompArea
```

si uso `print(k, v.numCompArea)` me arroja el siguiente error en el shell `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'numCompArea'`

Para el template uso

```html
{% for key, value in nombAreaNumComp %}
  <label>{{key}}: {{value}}</label>
{% endfor %}
```

Con ese codigo me imprime solo las claves sin su valor, es decir, lo mismo que esta arriba

Aun si **uso** el nombre de la clave ({{value.numCompArea)}} o **nombAreaNumComp.itmes** en el for no me imprime su valor. **A claro** fkarea__nameareaes es un join para llegar al nombre del area que esta en otra tabla como pueden ver si funciona **pero** no se como presentar lo en el template.

Por otro lado necesito poner un alias a este join **fkarea__nameareaes** pero no se como hacer lo, cuando es solo un campo se usa

```py
alias = Areas.objects.extra(select={'Nombre del area':'nameareaes'}).values('Nombre del area')
print(alias)
[{'Nombre del area': 'Información y alfabetización digital'}, {'Nombre del area': 'Comunicación y colaboración online'}, {'Nombre del area': 'Creación de contenidos digitales'}, {'Nombre del area': 'Seguridad en la red'}, {'Nombre del area': 'Resolución de problemas'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero que nada esto debería dar error:

```
for k, v in nombAreaNumComp:
  print(k, v)
```

El método `values` devuelve un QuerySet que devuelve diccionarios, en lugar de instancias de modelo, es decir se supone que estas iterando un **QuerySet no un diccionario**, por lo cual debería dar error.

Pero dices que funciona, y que te muestra **solo** las keys, entonces eso significa que el valor de `nombAreaNumComp` no es:

```
[{'fkarea__nameareaes': 'Información y alfabetización digital', 'numCompArea': 3}, {'fkarea__nameareaes': 'Comunicación y colaboración online', 'numCompArea': 6}, {'fkarea__nameareaes': 'Creación de contenidos digitales', 'numCompArea': 4}, {'fkarea__nameareaes': 'Seguridad en la red', 'numCompArea': 4}, {'fkarea__nameareaes': 'Resolución de problemas', 'numCompArea': 4}]
```

Lo ideal seria que mostraras el valor real de `nombAreaNumComp`...

---

Por ahora tomando en cuenta que el valor de `nombAreaNumComp` si sea:

```
[{'fkarea__nameareaes': 'Información y alfabetización digital', 'numCompArea': 3}, {'fkarea__nameareaes': 'Comunicación y colaboración online', 'numCompArea': 6}, {'fkarea__nameareaes': 'Creación de contenidos digitales', 'numCompArea': 4}, {'fkarea__nameareaes': 'Seguridad en la red', 'numCompArea': 4}, {'fkarea__nameareaes': 'Resolución de problemas', 'numCompArea': 4}]
```

Tienes que tener en cuenta que el QuerySet devuelve **diccionarios**, entonces tu bucle debería ser así:

```
for dict_instance in nombAreaNumComp:
    for key, value in dict_instance.items():
        print(f'{key} -> {value}')
```

Lo cual imprimiría algo así:

```
fkarea__nameareaes -> Información y alfabetización digital
numCompArea -> 3
fkarea__nameareaes -> Comunicación y colaboración online
numCompArea -> 6
fkarea__nameareaes -> Creación de contenidos digitales
numCompArea -> 4
fkarea__nameareaes -> Seguridad en la red
numCompArea -> 4
fkarea__nameareaes -> Resolución de problemas
numCompArea -> 4
```

Y si quieres replicar esto en tu template, entonces seria así:

```
{% for dict_instance in nombAreaNumComp %}
    {% for key, value in dict_instance.items %}
        <label>{{ key }}: {{ value }}</label>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

---

#### Actualización 1:

Ya entendí que es lo que quieres hacer, para hacerlo seria así:

> ```
> for dict_instance in nombAreaNumComp:
>     values = [*dict_instance.values()]
>     print(f'{values[0]}: {values[1]}')
> ```
>
> O puedes hacerlo asi:
>
> ```
> values = [(*dict_instance.values(),) for dict_instance in nombAreaNumComp]
>
> for value in values: print(f'{value[0]}: {value[1]}')
> ```

Obtendrás un resultado algo así:

```
Información y alfabetización digital: 3
Comunicación y colaboración online: 6
Creación de contenidos digitales: 4
Seguridad en la red: 4
Resolución de problemas: 4
```

Para hacerlo en tu template, habría que hacer una modificación en la vista:

> ```
> def view(request):
>     nombAreaNumComp = ...
>
>     values = [(*dict_instance.values(),) for dict_instance in nombAreaNumComp]
>     texts = [f'{value[0]}: {value[1]}' for value in values]
>
>     return render(request, '...', {'texts': texts})
> ```
>
> Y ahora tu template:
>
> ```
> {% for text in texts %}
>     <label>{{ text }}</label>
> {% endfor %}
> ```
>
> ---
>
> O en cambio, para mas personalisacion, puede ser tu vista asi:
>
> ```
> def view(request):
>     nombAreaNumComp = ...
>
>     values = [(*dict_instance.values(),) for dict_instance in nombAreaNumComp]
>
>     return render(request, '...', {'values': values })
> ```
>
> Y tu template:
>
> ```
> {% for values in values %}
>     <label>{{ values.0 }}: {{ values.1 }}</label>
> {% endfor %}
> ```
>
> El valor de `{{ values.0 }}` seria `fkarea__nameareaes` y el de `{{ values.1 }}` seria el de `numCompArea`.

Cualquiera de las dos formas es valida. Y obtendrás el resultado deseado en tu template.

---

#### Actualización 2:

**Para poner un alias a un campo, es algo complicado, ya que no hay una unica forma de hacerlo, ni hay un estandar.**

Para hacerlo hay que hacer truquitos o cosas asi xD. Por ejemplo, puedes hacerlo con *Managers* personalisados, o campos (`Field`) personalisados, etc.

Aqui, te adjunto una pregunta de alguien, que queria poner una alias a un campo:

- [**How to create an alias for Django Model field?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985466/how-to-create-an-alias-for-django-model-field)

En dicha pregunta hay respuestas que exlican como hacerlo, pero de varias maneras y tienen inconvenientes, desventajas, entre otras cosas. No te recomiendo hacerlo a menos de que sea **realmente necesario**, no lo hagas por comodidad o por "capricho" por asi decirlo, solo haslo cuando tengas una **muy buena razon para hacerlo**.

Comment: en parte si, la idea es presentar **Información y alfabetización digital**: 3
**Comunicación y colaboración online**: 6 y asi... necesito el  key si pero para backend o usar alias para presentar "Nomb Area": "Información", "Numero Comp": 3... y si me funciona

Comment: Ya te entendí, acabo de actualizar mi respuesta, échale un vistaso y recuerda aceptar mi respuesta marcando el visto en la parte izquierda de la respuesta :)

Comment: vaya gracias, y con respecto al alias del join **fkarea__nameareaes** es posible??

Comment: Como que alias? osea según el ejemplo que me dijiste, en realidad querías los valores de los campos no "alias", o eso yo interprete, quieres que el nombre de `fkarea__nameareaes` sea otro? algo así como un alias? O en SQL un `... column_name AS name`?

Comment: Si lo dije al inicio quiero poner un alias `column_name AS name ` y tambien el valor como ya esta en la actualizacion de tu respuesta

Comment: @Cristian acabo de actualizar mi respuesta con informacion al respecto, echale un vistaso.